# TYPO3 on IIS 7.5 - HTTP 500

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, typo3

I have a virtual server with Windows Server 2008 R2/IIS 7.5.

I set up PHP 5.2 with FastCGI, MySQL 5 and put TYPO3 on it. Which doesn't work. I just get an "Internal Server Error - 500", which pretty much sums it up. No additional information.

PhpMyAdmin is working flawlessly, I imported the database with it (migrating a locally developed installation to this server).

Any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS7 defaults to hiding detailed error messages. Add this to a file called `web.config` in the root of your site:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

That should force IIS to render the underlying error.